# ZK showing huge data with List box on internet explorer, cause javaScript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, listbox, zk

I am trying to  show about 300 header and 1000 row with zk listbox, but on Internet explorer it gives  "Stop running this script?" error. If I click no it continues and opens my list box. On firefox and ınternet Explorer 9 it works normal but I should use explorer 8 . Here my not working solution

```
<listbox id="listModel" rows="15" 
                                        mold="paging" pageSize="15">
                                        <listhead >
                                            <listheader id="${each}"  
                                                style="overflow:auto" label="${each}" width=" 250px"
                                                forward="onDoubleClick=onRemoveFromHeader"
                                                forEach="${comboModelColumns}"  />
                                            <custom-attributes
                                                headers="${each}" />
                                        </listhead>
                                        <listitem
                                            forEach="${listValues}">
                                            <listcell
                                                forEach="${listValues[forEachStatus.index]}"
                                                label="${each}" />
                                        </listitem>
                                    </listbox>
```

here `combomodelColumns` list of 300 string. and `listValues` is a list taht contains 1000 list. And each list contains about 300 string too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem.

this is my zk component

```
<listbox id="listModel" rows="15" 
                                    mold="paging" pageSize="15">


                                    <listhead >
                                        <listheader 
                                            style="overflow:auto" label="${each}" width=" 250px"
                                            forward="onDoubleClick=onRemoveFromHeader"
                                            forEach="${tmpHeaders}"  />
                                        <custom-attributes
                                            headers="${each}" />
                                    </listhead>
                                    <listitem
                                        forEach="${tmpListValue}">
                                        <listcell
                                            forEach="${tmpListValue[forEachStatus.index]}"
                                            label="${each}" />
                                    </listitem>
                                </listbox>
```

I created firtly only 18 header , but I took hole data in onotherlist. when I choose some header from my combobox , manually added to listbox headers and row data.

```
Listheader newheader = new Listheader();
    newheader.setLabel(listBox_Columns.getSelectedItem().getLabel());
    newheader.setWidth("250px");

    org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ComponentsCtrl.applyForward(newheader, "onRemoveFromHeader");

    listModel.getListhead().appendChild(newheader);

    for (int i = 0; i < listValues.size(); i++) {

        List tmpCurrentRow = (List) listValues.get(i);
        List tmpRows = new ArrayList();

        Listcell newCell = new Listcell(tmpCurrentRow.get(findIndexHeaderByName(listBox_Columns.getSelectedItem().getLabel(), allHeaders)).toString());

        ((Listitem) listModel.getItems().get(i)).appendChild(newCell);

    }
```

thats all.Also I added remove header function to remove added header and cells. It simply sets visibility false.

```
public void onRemoveFromHeader(ForwardEvent event) {


        Listheader listheader = (Listheader) event.getOrigin().getTarget();
        listheader.setVisible(false);

        listBox_Columns.setSelectedItem(null);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer unfortunately does not execute speeds at the same rate as Firefox and other browsers. If a thread takes longer than a few seconds to execute, IE offers this dialog to the user.

I would recommend that you paginate your listbox:

```
<listbox mold="paging" pageSize="5"/>
```

Additionally, ZK allows you to use paging events allow you to decide when to populate more data into your listbox, etc.

Take a look at:

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Supplementary/Paging

Comment: thansk for reply.I used paging but here problem was creatin 300 colum at ones. I found some fix for IE that solves this javascript reponse time problem.But it is not the best way ı think. I solved problem and here I will share.